# solving a modular equation $6x=3\operatorname{mod}27, 6x=2\operatorname{mod}10$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Determine the kernel of the following group homomorphism:
>   $$
> \phi\colon\mathbb Z/270\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/270\mathbb Z\colon\overline x\mapsto\overline{6x}.
> $$
>   Then find the solutions of the following system of equations in $\mathbb Z/270\mathbb Z$:
>   \begin{align}
> 6x=3\mod 27\\
> 6x=2\mod 10
> \end{align}

Since $6*45=270$, the kernel is $\{\overline{45}, \overline{90}, \overline{135}, \overline{180}, \overline{225}, \overline{270}\}$. Instead of working with $6x$, I solved the following equations:
\begin{align}
a=3\mod 27\\
a=2\mod 10,
\end{align}
using the Chinese remainder theorem. I found: $a=192=32*6$. So I would guess they are looking for this answer:
$$
\left\{\overline{32+k45}:k\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\right\}.
$$
But I'm a bit confused by their phrasing, because we initially solved for $x\in\{0,1,\dots,269\}$, and not for $\overline a\in\mathbb Z/270\mathbb Z$... So I could only sort of guess what I had to do, but could someone clarify their wording? Why can it be interpreted as: find $\overline a\in\mathbb Z/270\mathbb Z$, such that for
$$
\phi'=\theta\circ\phi,
$$
where
$$
\theta\colon\mathbb Z/270\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/27\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z\colon a\mapsto (a,a),
$$
we have $\phi'(\overline a)=(3,2)$.

*edit*

I think I got it: to find solutions in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ just means to find solutions modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   6x &\equiv 3 \pmod {27}\\
   2x &\equiv 1 \pmod{9} \\
    \color{red}{x} &\color{red}{\equiv} \color{red}{5 \pmod{9}} \\
\hline
   6x &\equiv 2 \pmod{10} \\
   3x &\equiv 1 \pmod{5} \\
    \color{red}x &\color{red}{\equiv} \color{red}{2 \pmod{5}} \\
\end{align}

\begin{array}{c|cc}
     &\mod 5  &\mod 9 \\
\hline
    9 & 4      & 0 \\
    5 & 0      & 5 \\
\hline
   \color{brown}{-9} & 1      & 0 \\
   \color{brown}{10} & 0      & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

$$
   \left. \begin{array}{c}
      x \equiv 5 \pmod 9 \\
      x \equiv 2 \pmod 5
   \end{array} \right\}
   \implies x \equiv \color{brown}{-9}(\color{red}2)
                    +\color{brown}{10}(\color{red}5) 
              \equiv 32 \pmod{45}
$$

Answer (score 0):

we can write $$6x=3+27m$$ and $$6x=2+10n$$ where $m,n$ are integers, from here we get
$$1=10n-27m$$ solving this Diophantine equation we get $$m=7+10k,n=19+27k$$ and from here you will get $x$